# Window Function - DENSE_RANK

Tags: mysql, sql

My requirement is - "In which year most films were released?". The following query works fine

```
SELECT release_year, count(film_id)
from film
GROUP BY release_year 
ORDER BY count(film_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

RESULT:

```
      +--------------+----------------+
      | release_year | count(film_id) |
      +--------------+----------------+
      |         2017 |            110 |
      +--------------+----------------+
```

But the problem with this query is if same no. of movies were released during year 2016 also (suppose), I will not get that unless i mention Limit 2 (again i may not know limit value). So I tried it using **DENSE_RANK()** window function but I am unable to do so.

Please suggest how `dense_rank()` query would be?

Comment: with cte_re as 
(SELECT release_year, count(film_id),dense_rank() over (order by film_id) as dr
from film group by release_year ORDER BY count(film_id) DESC)
select * from cte_re where dr=(maximum value of the rank under dr) ;

Hope this works..

Comment: 'So I tried it using DENSE_RANK() window function but I am unable to do so.' is uninformative do you get an error if so what is it , or were the results not what you expected? also what version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
    SELECT release_year, 
           COUNT(film_id) cnt, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(film_id) DESC) drnk
    FROM film
    GROUP BY release_year 
)
SELECT release_year, cnt
FROM cte
WHERE drnk = 1;
```